"Pyright reportMissingImports" error message is wrong. Why did I get this message and how can I prevent it from reappearing?
General Background:
I'm learning Python and chose to make Vim my IDE (PyCharm was recommended, but there's no regret in my choice with Vim. It's awesome!). I'm currently building a cheap flight finder OOP, using Amadeus' SDK installed in a virtualenv.
Set-up:
Vim: 9.0 (with plugins that include coc/nvim with coc-pyright 1.1337 , gruvbox, vim-commentary, and black); Pip: 20.0.2; Python: 3.8.10 [GCC 9.4.0]; OS: Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS on Windows 10 x86_64; Kernel: 5.15.153.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2; and Shell: bash 5.0.17
Specific problem:
Along with the SDK, I installed other packages, like requests, I thought I would need. As I dug in I realized I needed the Pandas package for my project, as well. So while in my venv with 4 buffers open, I typed:
:! pip install pandas
This opened a terminal session and installed Pandas successfully.
Then I sourced the venv with:
:! . venv/bin/activate
When I returned to Vim, the line calling Pandas gave the error "Import "pandas" could not be resolved (Pyright reportMissingImports)". I ran a test to confirm it was installed properly by opening a new Vim session, activating the venv, and calling the project. It worked, as expected. But with the glaring error message in my main project, I chose not to execute my code. I found out later, that had I simply ignored the error and run the code, it would have worked too. Why or what caused the Pyright error message to appear and how can I prevent it from giving me another false positive?

What do you mean by "Pandas was not recognized as being installed"? What didn't recognize Pandas as being installed? Vim doesn't know or care about whether or not your Python packages are installed and where. Use PyCharm.

To expand on romainl's comment, you will need either a tags file or an LSP client and server to "recognize" anything. Without it, Vim will only "remember" words from open buffers. What you describe is expected behavior unless you're using some plugin you're not telling us about. As it's written, it will be virtually impossible to answer your question. Learning two new things (Python and Vim) at the same time is challenging, consider dropping one for now.

Updating my venv and returning to Vim with those packages sourced may not be possible. But this is the best place for us to find out. Maybe there is a plugin that I should consider. I take it that's what this space is all about - asking, sharing, and learning. Also, I'm well over the steep learning curve with Vim and am quite happy with my .vimrc (not perfect, but it's fantastic for what I want to do). I could never think of using PyCharm or any other IDE now, but your comments are appreciated.

@HappyUmo Appreciated or not but there're clarifying questions in the comments and we expect you to [edit] and extend your question with more details.

Again, WHAT didn't recognize that Pandas was installed? Vim? Python? Something else?

Python did not recognize Pandas was installed. I think/hope the updated title and description that follows makes that clearer.

There are existing questions which address issues with pyright and venvs: Pyright is not finding imports from libraries in a virtualenv and How to set python interpreter in neovim for python language server depending on pyenv / virtualenv

@HappyUmo "Python did not recognize Pandas was installed." Still not enough info and doesn't have much sense. Which one of many Pythons you have on your system? Are you sure :!pip install installed packages into the Python that you expect? pip doesn't install packages for abstract Python, pip installs packages for exactly one Python — the same one it was run with.

@Friedrich Thanks. This gets to closer to my issue. I'm not sure I'll be able resolve it, but I will try.

@phd I'm running: Vim: 9.0; Python: 3.8.10 [GCC 9.4.0]; OS: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on Windows 10 x86_64; Kernel: 5.15.153.1 microsoft-standard-WSL2; Shell: bash 5.0.17. And yes, pip installed the package into Python successfully. But when I returned to Vim, the package gave me the error "Import "pandas" could not be resolved (Pyright reportMissingImports)" when I placed my cursor over the word Pandas. Had I simply ignored the error and run my code, it would have worked. Instead, I stop and decided to ask if what I was doing could be done, in this forum.

Please [edit] all the additional information into your question. A future reader should be able to understand it without having to read through a dozen comments.

@Friedrich Understood and done. I think that covers everything. Thanks.

The purpose of this command:
$ source .venv/bin/activate

is to change a bunch of environment variables for the current process and its eventual children, the most important being $PATH.
Those changes are carried over when you fork a new process (Vim, the Python REPL, a sub-shell, etc.) but the parent environment is typically copied into the child environment, making the two environments completely separate. Changing the parent environment has no effect on the child environment and vice-versa.
Activating a Python virtual environment is not something you do often and especially not something you do after installing a package, unless the package somehow requires it, which should be very rare and which is not the case with Pandas to begin with.
Now, when you do the following in Vim:
:!pip install pandas

you effectively:

Create a new sub-shell that inherits the parent's virtual environment.
Install pandas in that virtual environment.
Quit that sub-shell.

At no point did anything change in the child environment or in the parent environment. All that happened is that a bunch of files were added in a bunch of directories under .venv/. There is no need to "re-source" anything, so doing:
:!source .venv/bin/activate

in Vim serves no purpose whatsoever, as…

it does nothing package-specific,
whatever changes it does — if any — to the sub-shell's environment dies with it,
it can't be expected to do anything to Vim's environment or to its parent anyway.

Now let's go back to the initial, under-specified, problem:

You install Pandas in the current virtual environment.
Something complains that Pandas isn't installed.

I went trough the following steps in order to get a sense of what you are dealing with:

Create a dummy project and cd into it:
$ mkdir testpython
$ cd $_


Create a virtual environment:
$ python3 -m venv .venv


Activate it:
$ source .venv/bin/activate


Open a dummy Python file in Vim:
$ vim foo.py


Put some dummy code in foo.py:
import pandas as pd
s = pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
print(s)


Test it without Pandas installed:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/romlafou/Documents/foopython/foo.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'

shell returned 1

Well yeah, Pandas is not installed.

Install Pandas from Vim:
:!pip install pandas


Run the buffer through the interpreter:
:w !python3
0    1
1    2
2    3
3    4
4    5
dtype: int64

That's it. Vim doesn't complain, Python doesn't complain, the shell doesn't complain, the terminal emulator doesn't complain… Everything is fine.


FWIW, I also started a REPL in Vim's terminal with :term python3 and everything worked flawlessly. No complaint whatsoever about Pandas not being installed.
To sum it up:

a "virtual environment" is really a bunch of environment variables,
when you start Vim, it inherits the virtual environment of its parent process
installing a package in the current virtual environment is not expected to change the virtual environment, whether it is installed from within Vim or not,
the package is immediately available to any python sub-process (!python3 %, :w !python3, :term python3).

Which begs the question: what is complaining about missing Pandas after you have installed it. To which we still have no answer.
My hypothesis is that you are trying to do something like:
:py3file %

which indeed throws an ugly error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in <module>
  File "foo.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'

which is to be expected because the Python interpreter used by Vim under the hood is very unlikely to be the one in your .venv/bin/ and it is very unlikely to be aware of any project-specific virtual environment.
If you absolutely insist on using the :py* family of commands, then you should probably head off to :help if_pyth.txt and try to work something out.
But I wouldn't recommend going that path as the other methods, :[range]w !python3 being my favorite, all honor your virtual environments out of the box.

Thank you for clearing this up! It works! But...after following your steps, running the buffer, and returning to the code, if yours is like mine, you'll see (with your cursor over the word pandas, in line 1), an error saying "Import "pandas" could not be resolved (Pyright reportMissingImports)". I didn't go further to execute my code because of the glaring error referencing pandas. I don't know if this erroneous error counts as a glitch or where to get it corrected. But, it's great to know that you actually can install more packages as you go, without disrupting your workflow!

Thanks for your help in getting to the root of my problem.

The line you show to activate the virtual environment does not work in Vim:
:. venv/bin/activate

Vim interprets the . to stand for the current line and venv is not a valid Ex command. You'll get
E492: Not an editor command: . venv/bin/activate

You would need to run it in a shell using the :! command, like your call to pip above:
:!. venv/bin/activate

This will run successfully but is flawed as well. As explained in :help :! and :help 'shell', Vim will invoke a subshell and source activate there.
On completion of the command, the shell will exit and all changes to the environment will be lost.
The question is very unclear about the actual error and how it surfaces.
In case the error is caused by pylint, it may be worth noting that it has a hard time running in a virtual environment.
See pylint doesn't point to virtualenv python
As clarified in your comments to this answer, OP is using coc.nvim with coc-pyright and thus pyright (really, this should be in the question!) It boils down to correctly set up pyright. Related questions are Pyright is not finding imports from libraries in a virtualenv and How to set python interpreter in neovim for python language server depending on pyenv / virtualenv
Otherwise, it depends on whatever external command and plugin you're using. Vim itself doesn't do any code checking. There are plugins which will show the errors external static code checkers found.
If you could consider to restart Vim but want to keep buffers and options, you may be interested in :help :mksession and :help :mkview.

The suggestion to use Ctrl-Z to suspend Vim and then update the environment will not work on any OS, as far as I'm aware (I've confirmed this doesn't work on macOS). The environment of the parent process will be updated, sure, but the environment of Vim and its child processes will not be modified.

@RyanPatterson thanks to your comment and romainl's answer, I understood that Ctrl-Z would not work. I removed this misleading part from my answer.

I left the ! out, by accident, in describing the problem...sorry. I don't have may plugins, just COC, vim-commentary, grubox, and black. The error message that made me think I shouldn't execute my code said, "Import "pandas" could not be resolved (Pyright reportMissingImports)" Thanks for your help.

@HappyUmo coc.nvim is useful information. You're probably running coc-pyright and need to specify the path to venv as described in the plugin's readme. Note that pyright is a static analysis tool and your code may run flawlessly even if it shows errors and vice versa. This is especially true when configurations between pyright and python differ.

@HappyUmo the list of plugins and the exact error message are exactly the kind of information that's missing from your question. Please edit to include it.

@Friedrich Yes, I'm running coc-pyright 1.1337 with Pyright 1.1.337, but I don't have a Conda setup. I did, however, modify all three of my inlayHint attributes to false. Thanks for the explanation and help in clarifying my question.

Conda is unrelated. Disabling inlayHints will only hide the error, much better to set your tools up correctly. As far as I can tell, you should set python.venvPath to where your venv resides.

@Friedrich I created a pyrightconfig.json file and placed it in my project file. So, can/should I return the inlayHints to their defaults, now too?

@HappyUmo all I can do is read the documentation, as well. But: yes, return them to their defaults. You want to see the results of static code analyzers to find possible errors early.
